# How to make Downloads folder behave like a temp directory

Tags: directory, home-directory, tmp

In order to reduce disk space usage, I want to automate a temporary clean in my `Downloads` folder. I figured two ways to do so:

1) Changing the configurations of firefox, etc. to save files to `/tmp/` (this would require, for safety, changing the variable `TMPTIME` in `/etc/default/rcS` to 7 or more days);

2) Turning the `~/Downloads` folder into a temporary directory that behaves similarly to `/tmp/`, deleting old files. The problem is that in `/tmp` files are indiscriminately deleted in the end of the session; in `~/Downloads` folder it would be better to delete files by their creation date.

I'm not very sympathetic to the first option, since it requires a lot of config. I'd like some help to implement the second one. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of changing how the directory works, you could have a little clean-up script. It's easier to implement and probably less dangerous in the long run.

The following will delete anything over 7 days old in your `~/Download/` directory:

```
find ~/Download/ -mtime +7 -delete
```

You might want to test that by just removing the `-delete` segment and checking the files it returns. But once you're happy with it, you can schedule it to run once a day by running `crontab -e` and adding this on a new line:

```
@daily find ~/Download/ -mtime +7 -delete
```

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save and exit and you're done.

Comment: The `tmpwatch` or `tmpreaper` package are better approaches to cleaning up a directory, having been designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: +1 @MikeyB, but I would also put this in a script which runs at every boot, since a cronjob won't run if the machine is off when the job is due.

Comment: @scott why not just duplicate the line with `@reboot` instead of `@daily` to have the command run at boot as well